# is it possible to call javascript functions in cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber-java

I am a java developer,I have written few of the js files for UI related,My question is is it poosible to use my js functions in Cucumber feature file or how to inject my js into cucumber,thisOC is for eay way to do the automation.

Comment: Yes,you can use your js file in cucumber with the help of step definintion method.

Comment: Thank for the response,but using step definition we need to change the lot of code and its entirely different way,my POC is for using the existing cucumber scripts and call my js functions,let me know is any other way to do it.,Please share any link to understand.

Comment: I got a solution for this question,without using the step definitions.just call the function in feature file exactly written in js file,it returns the output. no need to import js files or gems or library.Thanks